# Typescript typeguard for any[] function parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, typeguards

Wondering if make sense to have this instance of typeguard check on a function like this:

```
Foo(value: any[]) {
    if (value instanceof Array) {
        Console.log('having an 
        array')
    } 
}
```

Since the parameter has been declared as an array of any does this automatically imply that runtime value should be always an instance of an array?

Is this a specific case in which any is involved and the typeguard is necessary?

What I mean is: does specifying the type of a parameter ensure that runtime that parameter is shown of that type in developer tools? In this case instance of that type represents a useless check..

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Hi I've edited the question hope it is more understandable now..

Comment: No, the types are only used at compile time. There is no TS at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition inside Foo() is of no significance as while developing compiler with throw an error if an array is not passed as param in the method.

Typeguards are only significant at compile time, because your transpiled code in javascript is shipped to the browser.